# Rails - Ruby gem merit score not adding if Model cannot be guessed from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, merit-gem

I am working with merit gem and I have a pages controller and an action 'fan'. I need the merit gem to add 10 score when user be a fan of a page. Modal is 'Fan'. Fan has a user.

```
score 10, :on => 'pages#fans', model_name: 'Fan', :to => :user
```

But this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: Did you define a `@fan` instance variable in the controller? It's possible you'll need a `@page` one, not exactly sure now on your case.

Comment: No, `@fan` instance variable is not there in the controller. But `@page` is there.

Comment: I don't think you need the `model_name: 'Fan'` option then.

Comment: I am manually giving the score now. Nothing given in the point_rules.rb is giving scores.

Comment: If you want to paste `pages#fans` source I may be able to help further, although your work-around is good.

Comment: Controller code is given below:
`@page = Page.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
    fan = @page.fans.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
    if fan.blank?
      fan = @page.fans.create(:user_id => current_user.id) 
    end
    @page.reload
    render :json => {:count => @page.fans.count}`

Comment: Is there anyway to know the highest point earned by a user? (I need to subtract the points sometimes)

Comment: Your rule will start working if you define the `@fan` instance variable, and it has to be the one found or the one just-created.
I don't understand your last question, but points are just an SQL table, you can query it/inspect it at will. It's merit_scores_points.

Comment: Let me elaborate - user earns points which are redeemable. So we want to display both "Lifetime" i.e., gross number & the net points (after redemption, if any) available as on a given date. So we rank users on lifetime, net number etc. I am wondering what is the best way to do this. Sorry if this question is beyond the scope of the gem...